# Two \tweak in a LilyPond variable

Tags: lilypond

Per the manual, I am trying to define a variable that inserts "***p*** *dolce*" dynamics.

```
pDolce = \tweak DynamicText.self-alignment-X #LEFT
         #(make-dynamic-script
           (markup "p" #:normal-text #:italic "dolce"))

\relative c' {
    c \pDolce c c c
}
```

But what if I need to tweak two properties? This doesn't compile:

```
pDolce = \tweak DynamicText.self-alignment-X #LEFT
         \tweak DynamicText.X-offset = 0
         #(make-dynamic-script
           (markup "p" #:normal-text #:italic "dolce"))

\relative c' {
    c \pDolce c c c
}
```

with a message:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting \header
```

How do I tweak two properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second tweak doesn't seem to work at all.

To get it to work just change:
`\tweak DynamicText.X-offset = 0`
to
`\tweak DynamicText.X-offset #0`

Comment: You also don't need the #.